# Cannot add Visual C++ Runtime Package reference to Windows Phone project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, unity-game-engine, windows-phone-8.1

After exporting a Unity project to Windows Phone, I am missing a reference in Visual Studio. The reference is Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Package for Windows.

[image: missing reference]

The files and dlls exist where they have to be but there I cannot add a reference to them in the reference manager because it does not exist there. Browsing and adding them directly also brings up a error saying the dll is not compatible.

[image: No reference]

Does anyone know how this reference can be fixed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We had similar problem caused by "incorrect" version of used Visual Studio. Unity created a project for VS2015 which had reference for the newer version of the *Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Package*. When we opened the project in VS 2013, a similar problem occurred. So the solution was to:

- Open it in VS 2015.
- Or change reference of the library to older version.
- Or have more VS versions on the machine.

Hope this help